# Shoutmeloud notification on Mac

Tags: virus

I started lately getting some ads notification on my Mac from "ShoutMeLoud"
I don't know if it is related to Chrome or not.
Is that a virus?

Comment: Your question lacks details. Have you scanned you're system? Would you provide a link or describe this "virus"?

Comment: What is "ads notification"? ShoutMeLoud is a blog. Are you saying Chrome warns you when you try to goto the ShoutMeLoud website? Or, if you're using Chrome you might have clicked "Allow" when the website asked if you wanted notifications. You can turn this off easily in your settings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's web push notifications. You can disable it from your browser settings.